# Does adding the 'final' keyword to methods in anonymous classes have any effect?

Tags: java

*Note: I'm not asking the age-old question about why outer variables accessed in an anonymous class need to be declared final.*

When creating an anonymous class in Java, you can add additional methods if you desire:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        internal();
    }

    public void internal() {
        .. code ..
    }
};
```

However, Java also allows you to declare the additional methods as `final`:

```
public final void internal() { ... }
```

**My question is:** Aren't those methods already effectively final, and does adding the `final` keyword have any effect?

Comment: Because it makes parsing simpler?

Comment: You'll be able to tell whether or not the method is `final` if you use reflection on that class.

Comment: Well, Java already allows you to write `final` on methods in classes that are themselves `final`, even though it's strictly unnecessary...

Comment: So it sounds like the answer is, "Yes, they're already `final` by default, but Java allows you to be explicit should you choose."

Comment: There are many things that can be explicitly declared even though they're already implicit. One example is `public abstract` interface methods. I don't think it's valid to ask why the language designers didn't go out of their way to disallow possibly redundant but ultimately harmless syntax.

Comment: That falls a bit under the table but the answer to whether adding `final` has *any* effect is "yes". You'll suddenly see it via reflection and CGLIB proxies are no longer allowed to override "implicitly final" methods (also implicitly final classes).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Java specification about [`final` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3) says:

> A `private` method and all methods declared immediately within a `final` class (§8.1.1.2) behave as if they are `final`, since it is impossible to override them.

and from [Anonymous Class Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5):

> An anonymous class is always implicitly `final` (§8.1.1.2).

Therefore, an anonymous class is already `final`, which makes all of its methods `final`. You can add the `final` modifier but it is redundant.

---

An interesting comment by [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) shows that the Reflection API actually won't report the `final` modifier for an anonymous class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main anon = new Main() {};
        System.out.println(Modifier.isFinal(anon.getClass().getModifiers())); // prints false
    }
}
```

This is apparently a known bug ([JDK-8129576](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8129576)) which is scheduled to be fixed in Java 9.

Comment: Thanks for the concise and well-referenced answer!

Comment: [JVM doesn't play by the rules.](http://ideone.com/IyPWp8) Or whatever compiles it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I found [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4777101) which is "Not An Issue" =/.

Comment: I have faith in the language developers!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ha, I found [another one](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8129576) scheduled to be fixed in Java 9! (edited)

Comment: I came by this trying to create a CGLIB proxy from an anonymous class, which worked. I expect quite a bit of code to break with that fix.